# Issue with deadlock and lock timeout exceeded on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, centos

Well, I'm having trouble at some update, delete and insert.

I figured out that typing **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS** on mysql will show the last deadlock:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
171128  2:10:22
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 23 2653931321, ACTIVE 3 sec, process no 19519, OS thread id 123471633422080 inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 57910754, query id 25462868783 localhost 127.0.0.1 ***** update
INSERT IGNORE INTO tb01 (`id_agendamento`,`nm_usuario`,`id_usuario`,`dt_cache`) values ('3000373','fulano','27861269','2017-11-28 02:10:19')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6137 page no 54196 n bits 672 index `id_agendamento` of table `dbinfos`.`tb01` trx id 23 2653931321 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 259 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 3; hex adc835; asc   5;; 1: len 8; hex 3237383631323639; asc 27861269;; 2: len 4; hex 80921b71; asc    q;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 23 2653285408, ACTIVE 143 sec, process no 19519, OS thread id 123471351097088 fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 468
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
109238 lock struct(s), heap size 13187056, 26792384 row lock(s), undo log entries 12217038
MySQL thread id 57906706, query id 25461633354 localhost 127.0.0.1 ***** updating
DELETE from tb01 WHERE dt_cache < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 6137 page no 54196 n bits 672 index `id_agendamento` of table `dbinfos`.`tb01` trx id 23 2653285408 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 259 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 3; hex adc835; asc   5;; 1: len 8; hex 3237383631323639; asc 27861269;; 2: len 4; hex 80921b71; asc    q;;
```

but I can't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Not a good fit for SO. After some more research, and if there is still a question that fits, recommend going to https://dba.stackexchange.com/  This is a good place to start with answering this question, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess here but aren't you just opening a transaction in you code and doing some heavy work after while leaving it open ?

If not, then yeah dba.stackexchange may be the best place to ask that.